# How to add module in spyder IDE of python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, spyder

I started learning machine learning. I was stuck in the IDE where I was unable to add the module of sklearn in my Python file. It was showing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'

Comment: This is really not much to work with for us... You may want to have a look here and edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this [link](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) on guide on how to install libraries in Spyder. If you are on ubuntu, then the best thing for you would be to install packages using `pip` as that will install and settle dependencies. You can also use `conda` for that. Make sure that python environment that spyder is using is same as the python environment you are installing the package for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am sorry that i didnt mention that i am using Anaconda for this and i am unable to use sklearn componets in my python code. I tried your way but still the problem is same.

Answer (score 0):

Great that you started learning machine learning, enjoy the journey!

I would advise you to install python using Anaconda https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

If you do this most of the modules you will need will be pre-installed.

Comment: i am sorry that i forgot to mention . I am using Anaconda. I am unable to use sklearn module in my python code.